# android getting multiple response at a time

Tags: android, server

I am trying to send a form that contains some text fields and an image. I wish to send all this data to a single URL. I learned to send texts and later I learned to send image.

Now the problem is when I am sending the form data to the server. Multiple requests are being sent separately, one for the text fields and other for the image field. Can somebody tell me how to send both these text and image through a single request?

This is my code to send text:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(isConnected()) {
        feedbackName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feedback_name);
        feedbackEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feedback_email);
        String email=feedbackEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
        feedbackComment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.feedback_comment);

        String name = feedbackName.getText().toString();

        String comment = feedbackComment.getText().toString();
        if ((name.matches("")) || (name.matches("")) || (email.matches("")) || (comment.matches(""))) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill up all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            if (email.matches(emailPattern)) {
                new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/post-feedback");
            } else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Email Address",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}             

public static String POST(String url, feedbackData feedbackData){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("name", feedbackData.getName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("email", feedbackData.getEmail());
        jsonObject.accumulate("comment", feedbackData.getComment());

        json = jsonObject.toString();

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return result;
}

private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        feedbackData feedbackData = new feedbackData();
        feedbackData.setName(feedbackName.getText().toString());
        feedbackData.setEmail(feedbackEmail.getText().toString());
        feedbackData.setComment(feedbackComment.getText().toString());

        return POST(urls[0],feedbackData);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Feedback send successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;
}
```

And this is the code I used to send the image to the server:

```
private class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void> {

    Bitmap image;
    String name;
    public UploadImage(Bitmap image,String name){
        this.image=image;
        this.name=name;

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
        String encodedImage= Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend=new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",encodedImage));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams=getHttpRequestParams();

        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post=new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS);

        try{

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}
```

Comment: To send text messages use same trick as Image thats all

Comment: like new BasicNameValuePair("text1", "text1content") and so on

Comment: In above code to send image I have sent a textfield named name along with the image.Is that all ok to send text to server

Comment: yeah!!! that's enuf

Comment: Thanks man for the tip

Comment: Glad to help you...